# PyInstaller cannot check for assembly dependencies

Tags: python-3.6, pyinstaller

I am trying to make Tkinter GUI module with a build option to build Exes after the user puts some inputs & I don't want him to install python and pyinstaller to be able to Compile the code to Exe.

Using Python 3.6.0

I made 2 python scripts first-named compiler.py & other hello.py
hello.py`print("Hello World")`

compiler.py

```
import PyInstaller.__main__
import ctypes
import win32ctypes
from win32ctypes import pywin32
from win32ctypes.pywin32 import pywintypes
import os

def compiling():
    PyInstaller.__main__.run([
        # '--name=%s' % package_name,
        '--onefile',
        '--windowed',
        # '--add-binary=%s' % os.path.join('resource', 'path', '*.png'),
        # '--add-data=%s' % os.path.join('resource', 'path', '*.txt'),
        # '--icon=%s' % os.path.join('resource', 'path', 'icon.ico'),
        os.path.join('hello.py'),  # my_package is a Directory
        # '--version-file=%s' % os.path.join('assembly.txt'),
    ])
compiling()
```

when I try to Compile compiler.py with pyinstaller it compiles successfully
with -->pyinstaller --onefile --console compiler.py

but when I try to run the exe it throws

```
PyInstaller cannot check for assembly dependencies.
Please install pywin32-ctypes.

pip install pywin32-ctypes
```

What I Have Tried?
1-i installed pywin32-ctypes successfully
2-Tried to compile compiler.py with different alternatives other than pyinstaller
3-cx-freeze & nuitka both of them throw the same error when I Run after compiling.
4- tried using Python 3.7.5 on other machine start new fresh Throw the Same Error
the reason I choose pyinstaller because it can build 1 EXE

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3892

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3793

[Unable to run PyInstaller - "Please install PyWin32 or pywin32-ctypes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52194396/unable-to-run-pyinstaller-please-install-pywin32-or-pywin32-ctypes)

All those Failed As Well is it something I am Doing Wrong or is Pyinstaller Problem

Answer (score 9):

An old question but maybe someone could face the same issue.
I found a solution and it works for me.

Installing this module solves the problem

```
pip install cffi
```

After installing, I tried the build again. Gives error-like warning.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
```

You can fix this warning via installing pywin32

```
pip install pywin32
```

I hope it helped someone else.

Comment: I experienced the same issue as OP, and cffi was my culprit as well - but it was already installed. My resolution was to upgrade it from 1.12.3 to 1.14.1 via 'pip install --upgrade cffi'.  So, thank you for putting me on this track!

Answer (score 8):

I had the exact same issue.

The fix for me was making an edit to a couple of lines in the Pyinstaller compat.py file.

Navigate to your python directory -> Lib -> site-packages -> Pyinstaller.

Open compat.py and look for the following:

```
if is_win:
    try:
        from win32ctypes.pywin32 import pywintypes  # noqa: F401
        from win32ctypes.pywin32 import win32api
    except ImportError:
        # This environment variable is set by seutp.py
        # - It's not an error for pywin32 to not be installed at that point
        if not os.environ.get('PYINSTALLER_NO_PYWIN32_FAILURE'):
            raise SystemExit('PyInstaller cannot check for assembly dependencies.\n'
                         'Please install pywin32-ctypes.\n\n'
                         'pip install pywin32-ctypes\n')
```

Change both of those import statements to import the modules themselves instead of trying to grab them from win32ctypes.pywin32.

```
    #from win32ctypes.pywin32 import pywintypes  # noqa: F401
    #from win32ctypes.pywin32 import win32api
    import pywintypes
    import win32api
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, it looks like PyInstaller doesn't like running in a virtual environment. `deactivate`ing the venv, then `pip install pyinstaller` and `pyinstaller pyinstaller.spec` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this on Windows on command prompt, first navigate using cd, till reach the folder Scripts:

**C:\Users\john\Envs\yourEnv\Scripts**

You'll see a pyinstaller.exe

Then call it on cmd:

```
    pyinstaller --onefile --clean --name myApp "C:\path\to\your\script\example.py"
```

The resulting folders will be Dist and Build and they will be on first path you see here **"C:\Users\john\Envs\yourEnv\Scripts"**. The file .exe is on Dist.

Answer (score 0):

I  had similar issue.The above methods didnt work.I used env method ,(env) C:\Users\RAMAJAYAM>python -m PyInstaller  --name "tkinterapp1.py" "C:\Users\RAMAJAYAM\tkinterapp1.py" and compiled successfully.Exe works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I have figure it out the `pip3 install pyinstaller` was installing it in the `~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts` directory. I had to to uninstall it via `pip3 uninstall pyinstaller`. Then navigate to the python3 root install directory then run `python.exe -m pip install pyinstaller`.

Not sure what this means, but I'm no longer getting the following error:

```
PyInstaller cannot check for assembly dependencies.
Please install pywin32-ctypes.

pip install pywin32-ctypes
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and had to upgrade pyinstaller using

```
pip install --upgrade pyinstaller
```

It must be some kind of problem with the packages pyinstaller uses, It might have updated the packages while upgrading pyinstaller too.

Answer (score 0):

i got this broblem too.
i fixed it...

first -> uninstall pywin32-ctypes -> pip uninstall pywin32-ctypes
second -> install again -> pip install pywin32-ctypes

maybe this working ..!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I had modified the `.spec` file generated by PyInstaller and provided the wrong virtual environment path in the `Analysis`. The virtual environment didn't exist, so PyInstaller could not check for assembly dependencies.