# How to resolve "PyInstaller cannot check for assembly dependencies" at runtime

Tags: python, plugins, pyinstaller, pywin32

I'm attempting to package a Python program with pyinstaller that loads python modules at runtime from a `plugins` subfolder. All works, except when packaged with pyinstaller.

I think I need to add a runtime hook that updates hiddenimports when the packaged exe starts like this:

```py
import os

from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules


def hook(mod):
    # Specify the subfolder
    subfolder = "plugins"
    
    # Get the path to the subfolder
    subfolder_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(mod.__file__), subfolder)

    # Collect submodules from the specified subfolder
    hiddenimports = collect_submodules(subfolder_path)

    # Add the hidden imports to the analysis object
    mod.hiddenimports.extend(hiddenimports)
```

and package with

```bash
pyinstaller --runtime-hook=runtime-hook.py  --onefile .\app.py
```

but when the EXE runs it fails with:

```bash
PyInstaller cannot check for assembly dependencies.
Please install pywin32-ctypes.

pip install pywin32-ctypes
```

before the hook executes & `pywin32-ctypes` is already installed.

Other solutions I've found through search (below) haven't helped - any ideas?

- [Updating compat.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52194396/unable-to-run-pyinstaller-please-install-pywin32-or-pywin32-ctypes)
- [Installing cffi and pywin32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59638691/pyinstaller-cannot-check-for-assembly-dependencies#61644946)